Why do minor versions become majors when I turn versioning off and then on again?
We use minor and major versioning in our SharePoint library due to approval workflows behind the scenes for revisions and publications. I often want to make very small changes to major versions without bumping them up to the next major number, so I turn versioning off and then on again.
However, I've found that when I do this, any minor revisions that are in the approval process get bumped up to the next major revision.
Is there any way to prevent this from happening?
